# Making a notification icon with notification count

Tags: html, css

I want to make a notification icon on my website like facebook. Facebook shows you notification icon on the top left corner.
On facebook, there is number of notifications beside the icon. I want to make the same thing. I want to show the number of notifications beside the notification icon just like facebook. I have created this code for this:

```
<style>
    .icon {
        width:30px; 
        height:30px;
    }
    .txt {
        padding:-10px 0 0 10px;
        background:red; 
        font-size:xx-small;
    }
</style>

<div class="icon">
    <img src="icon.bmp" alt="none" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <div class="txt">10</div>
</div>
```

But it is not happening. Please anyone help me how can I make it same like facebook. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcel. It's really awesome answer. You will be glad to know that This answer also helped me to find the appropriate answer for many of my questions. I am very much grateful to you.

Comment: Good to hear that, so then please accept the answer so that the question isn't "open" anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just use `position: relative;` for the icon and `position: absolute;` for the text.
Define the distance to the icon with `top` and `left`.

```css
.icon {
    width:30px; 
    height:30px;
    position: relative;
}
.txt{
    background-color:red;
    font-size:xx-small;
    position: absolute;
    padding:2px;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d" alt="none" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <div class="txt">10</div>
</div>
```

I would also define the icon as a background image of `.icon` with css and remove the `img` tag.